# How can I unit test an Angular service that registers a callback on its dependency?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, signalr, jasmine

I have an AngularJs service that depends on a SignalR client for push based updates.

`MyService` registers a function  with the SignalR proxy for handling the update, which is called when the SignalR server calls the clientside method `receiveUpdate`, like so:

```
app.factory('MyService', function ($rootScope, signalRClient) {

signalRClient.proxy.on('receiveUpdate', function (update) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        handleUpdate(update);
    });
});

function handleUpdate(update) {
    // ....
}

return {
    getUpdates: function () {
        // ....
    }
}
```

});

How can I mock the `signalRClient` such that I can isolate the logic in `MyService`? How can I fake the call to `receiveUpdate` to pass in an update object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends a bit on how you set up your specs, I tend to load any modules in a `beforeEach` for each scenario and would do it like this.

```
var myMock;
var receiveUpdate;

beforeEach(module('whateverModuleSignalRClientIsIn', function($provide) {
    myMock = {
        proxy: {
            on: function(id, callback) {
                receiveUpdate = callback;
            }
        }
    };
    $provide.value('signalRClient', myMock);
}));

beforeEach(module('whateverModuleMyServiceIsIn'));

beforeEach(inject(function(MyService) {
    // MyService will not be instantiated untill it has been injected
    // and at this point signalRClient has been replaced with the mock already
}));

it('receives updates', function() {
    //This should trigger the callback in your service
    receiveUpdate({});
});
```

That will make sure your service-module gets loaded with a mocked version of `myService`.

How you implement the actual mock depends a bit on what the service looks like. You seem to be registering a callback so I would just make the mock have a method `on` on a `proxy` property and then store its argument (your callback) in a reference that is available from the specs. Then you should be able to simply invoke it when you want to.

Comment: It's your last paragraph that I'm interested in - can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: Well I don't know much about your codebase, but added some more details that should at least get you started.